# How to send push notifications to multiple devices using GCM and java

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I followed [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vd8bIkE29U4) and was able to register one device with GCM and to push notification to one device, I would like to know how to register multiple devices with GCM and push notifications to all devices and would also like to know how to send a device specific notification,for eg: If a person is within 1-2 kms of a particular area send notifications about that area only to that particular person.

**EDIT**
I know there where a lot of similar questions but none of them had a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some very good references for this. The links have samples too

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

[https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start][3]

Hope this helps
Anant